# Search and replace is adding not replacing

Tags: python, search, replace

I am trying to find this string in a file:

```
/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

And replace it with

```
#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

But there are cases where it already reads #/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py. So my program is replacing it with a double `##` so it looks like this:

```
##/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

How can I prevent the double ## ??

```
with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    typos = data.replace('/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py', '#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py')
with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(typos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression with a negative lookbehind.

```
import re

with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    typos = re.sub(r'(?<!#)/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp\.py', '#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py', data)

with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(typos)
```

Comment: Awesome.... Learn something new everyday